# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject

Tags: java, web-services, groovy, junit

Getting error when trying to test Jersey web services

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
```

.

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.expect;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest  {

    @Test
    public void testUserFetchesSuccess() {
        expect().
                body("id", equalTo("1")).
                when().
                get("/service");
    }


}
```

What does it mean? How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I downloaded and installed groovy-all. Now I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar.<init>(ResponseParserRegistrar.groovy)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:346)
    at SimpleTest.testUserFetchesSuccess(SimpleTest.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Download the groovy-all.jar and add it to project class path. Then delete your project manifest and a regenerate it or add it manually.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Download the `groovy-all.jar` and add it to the classpath.

With Maven, add this to your dependencies ([browse groovy-all on mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If I add the dependency to pom.xml. And use mvn to build a jar of my project. Do I also need add the groovy-all.jar to the classpath?

Comment: @JonahCui it depends on what you are building and how.

Comment: Now I have a project that start by `java -jar`. And I create a new `classloader` to load plugin(jar package). I use groovy in my plugin.

Comment: @JonahCui If you do not include the dependencies to the jar, you have to add the dependencies to the classpath.

Comment: Surprisingly, I am working with rest assured with JAVA and suddenly I see this error. Adding a groovy jar file resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and surprisingly I was working with RestAssured. I struggled for the entire day to get this fixed.

I updated maven's groovy-all (version 3.0.0-beta-1) dependency with the latest one and this worked absolutely fine and I had added this dependency on the top in pom.xml. Hope this will help some folks :)

Comment: The trick is that the dependency on groovy must be *before* the rest-assured :)

Answer (score -1):

go to ireports and select tools and then options ->ireport ->select lanaguage as java

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you need to define the runner with an annotation above your class?

In my case it's

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
```